# Nightly updates to Bintray is not synced to JCenter

Tags: artifactory, bintray, jcenter

We have a few artifacts hosted on Bintray and synced to JCenter. In all versions, we have a special, nightly-updated version, which is named "0.0.0-nightly". We push a new "0.0.0-nightly" for each artifact everyday. It had been working well for at least a year.

Starting from Dec 6 2019, we found that the synchronization was broken. Nothing was changed from our side, but the "0.0.0-nightly" artifacts on JCenter got very outdated (rolled back almost to July 2019). And those artifacts on JCenter have never been updated for weeks, while those on Bintray are updated well. It happens to all artifacts we host - nearly 10+ packages got impacted.

How can I fix this discrepancy? Or is it actually not supported to update existing versions on Bintray?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. all the versions are now immutable with bintray jcenter.
Which means you cannot override existing versions anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! If possible, could you please help give an official announcement or doc for this change? Thanks!